# Can I "move" a folder between two shares on a Netgear ReadyNAS without copying?

Tags: ssh, nas, readynas

I have a private folder on my ReadyNAS. It's not technically a share, since it's the user folder of my ReadyNAS user. In this folder I have about a terabyte of videos that I want to move to a share called "Public". If I just "move" the video folder between the two mounted network locations through Windows it's just going to copy the files, which will take ages.

Is there anything I can do to actually *move* the files just as I would move any file on my local disk? Is it possible to get SSH access to the NAS, for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the add-on [Enable Root SSH Access](http://www.readynas.com/?p=4203). Connect to the NAS using [Putty](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/&ei=BlqcUfOODqz24QTh_4CoCQ&v6u=https://s-v6exp1-ds.metric.gstatic.com/gen_204?ip=84.202.181.87&ts=1369201158412328&auth=3jna7h3lkgedshwbvptfvzoeyqrje444&rndm=0.9938198551535606&v6s=2&v6t=2393&usg=AFQjCNEtEh-zdWFiiosvMznjktZ3Wxpq-A&sig2=UWrWUkyql4NX0qk9cOUp2A&bvm=bv.46751780,d.bGE) or any other SSH client with the user name "root" and the same password as the admin user of the control panel. The user homes are located in `/c/homes` and the shares are under `/c`. In my case, this did the trick:

```
mv /c/homes/tomas/Series /c/Public/Series
```

And voilà, one terabyte of video moved to a different share in under 5 minutes (including the time it took to install the add-on and restart the NAS.)